# install web service on my server c# dotnet2 websitepanel

Tags: c#, web-services, installation, asmx, web-hosting

i have simple code that get some parameters via web service and put it in my database (her is sql server)

this project publish on my server in my local network and worked properly but when i install it on my server not worked

my server is [websitepanel](http://www.websitepanel.net/) and my site hosted there and worked properly

i create website there named web.mydomain.com

then ftp my files in the folder that grant permission to it to BROWSE

then when i type my folder like: web.mydomian.com/myfolder i can browse asmx file there

but when i enter full address of my web service and config web.config with my correct configs of my database and etc. error occurred...

http://web.learnkey.ir/msbservice/MSBService.asmx

> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'MSBService.MSBService'.

Comment: What App Pool is it running under?

Comment: how can i view the app pool? in this control panel?

Answer (score 0):

i created directory msbservice manually

when i search Google and found and read some articles, in one of these [articles](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/838706ac-6763-455b-95bd-1432a9ccc6be/could-not-create-type-error-deploying-webservice) i remember that i forget to create virtual directory

Just go to the control panel and create virtual directory. and permit to browse and everything work OK